# What portion of the energy carried by lightning is lost as ionization, heat, light, sound and other phenomena before it hits the ground?

Tags: lightning, ionization-energy

What portion of the energy carried by lightning is lost as heat, light and sound, by ionizing the atmosphere or to other phenomena the space between its source and the ground?

How does it vary between the leader, the return stroke and the continuous discharge we see at the end?

Comment: This seems to be able to vary tremendously. Consider cloud-to-cloud lightning, for example, where no ground is involved.